# MySQLWorkbench Simultaneous schema editing

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

So, for a group project I want to design an SQL database. How can I design the database simultaneously with other members of my team? Any server running tips and instructions are quite welcome, since I am a complete newbie at this.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL

Comment: So the server is not just for user querries but can accomodate simultaneous admin editing?